# Third Party APK wont install on Genymotion 2021

Tags: networking, android-emulator, apk, emulation, genymotion

I'm trying to install an app from an apk on Genymotion but it always reaches around 97% and then keeps saying installation failed, works on my unrooted mobile phone though.

I've tried:

1. Turning off Play Protect,
2. Allowing from unknown sources,
3. Bringing the apk from desktop to geny instead of directly downloading inside geny.

And yes, I've tried them all together as well.

Is the app detecting an unrooted system? And if so is there a way I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your APK for x86 or ARM? If it is for ARM, you need to install ARM translation tools first.